# How to remove cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With Jquery, I am trying to make a function similar to the filtering system used in this website([example](http://www.anthropologie.com/anthro/category/dresses/clothes-floorskimmers.jsp?&id=CLOTHES-FLOORSKIMMERS&facetSelected=true&itemCount=100))

If you click one of the filter elements, it will be displayed in another area. You can remove the selected filter by just clicking it.

My code works for cloning a filter element and displaying it in another area but 
I am having a trouble with removing it.

I did hours of research but could not find any solution so your help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code

---html---

```
    <div id="filter-selected>
       <ul>
          <!--selected element comes here -->
       </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="filter-options">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <!--clicking this list will clone itself to the above area-->
               <span>Value1</span>
           </li>
           <li>
               <!--clicking this list will clone itself to the above area-->
               <span>Value2</span>
           </li> 
       </ul>
    </div>
```

---Jquery---

```
$('#filter-options > ul > li').click(function(event){
    var $filter = $(this).children('span').clone();

    $filter.appendTo('#filter-selected > ul').wrap('<li class="filtering"></li>');
});

$(.filtering').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the elements are created dynamically, You need event delegation

```
$('#filter-selected').on('click', '.filtering', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing  string quote on left side `'` of `.filtering` which might be a problem.

```
$(.filtering').click(function(){
```